# Situation of schema_migration after handy delete from it

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

30 minutes ago, I went to MySQL and to the database that I used it in RoR. Then I went to `schema_migration` and I type

```
DELETE FROM schema_migration WHERE version=20120110152044;
```

After doing this work, I type `rake db:migrate` and I expect that the migration that I deleted some minutes ago will be added to `schema_migration` again but I face to this message:

> "MySQL2::ERROR Table 'football_leagues' already exist .... "

Can someone tell me reason of this message?

Answer (score 1):

Your 20120110152044 migration probably creates the `football_leagues` table with something like:

```
create_table :football_leagues do |t|
    #...
```

in the `up` or `change` method. Removing an entry from the `schema_migrations` table won't rollback the migration, it just changes the record of which migrations where done. You probably need to go back into MySQL and drop the `football_leagues` table by hand:

```
mysql> drop table football_leagues;
```

If you need to keep `football_leagues` around then you'll have to change your migrations to not try to create `football_leagues` again.

You can use `rake db:rollback` to rollback a migration instead of trying to edit `schema_migrations` by hand, editing `schema_migrations` should only be done if you're certain that you know exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score -1):

I don't want to sound patronizing, but it is because you are trying to create a table called football_leagues when it already exists.  Run `rake db:drop db:migrate` to delete the table (and any other tables in the database) and re-run the migration. **You will lose all your data in that database.**

Comment: now , how can I put version of that migration into schema_migration?

Comment: Are you really suggesting that the OP drop the whole database just to fix a single table? Are you insane or just malicious?

Comment: @muistooshort He has obviously screwed up his migration by playing around with his database directly.  I was pretty clear that it would cause data loss.  Doing what I said will revert it to how it was.

Comment: Dropping the whole database just to fix one little problem makes no sense and will cause more harm than good.